# Insert to MySql from c# failed

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem with a MySql insert ... this is my Code:

```
    public class struc
    {
        public string Product;
        public string Underproduct;
        public string Version;
    }

    static void DatabaseConection(List<struc> Data)
    {
    string connString = "right connection info";
        string insertQuery = "Insert into freigabedaten (produktname,unterprodukt,version,freigabestatus) values (productInfo.Product,productInfo.Underproduct,productInfo.Version,'4')";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);

        conn.Open();

        foreach (var productInfo in Data)
        {
                MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand Command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

                try
                {
                    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
        });

        conn.Close();
    }
```

But i get always the Exeption:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Unknown column
>   'productInfo.Product' in 'field list'"

My Database table structure is: 
[Databasetablescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gh7H.png)

can someone help me please?

Comment: What is productinfo

Comment: productInfo is a Object from the struc Class, I use it to read the entrys from the list<struc> Data

Comment: There is no column name product, try with my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

If productInfo is a C# Struct/Class you need to add the values manually to the Query string.

```
string insertQuery = "Insert into freigabedaten (produktname,unterprodukt,version,freigabestatus) values ('"+productInfo.Product+"','"+productInfo.Underproduct+"','"+productInfo.Version+"','4')";
```

If productInfo is another table you'll need to query these values beforehand.

Comment: Thats Worked well, but now i get this exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Version_100,4)' at line 1"}

Comment: I edited the answer, you need to wrap strings in quotation marks just like you have to do in C#.

Tetsuya Yamamoto's answer is cleaner and you should use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you're passing all `INSERT` query arguments as part of query string, not as reference to `productInfo` object which contains column names (which they're treated as table names instead).

Use a parameterized MySQL query like this:

```
string insertQuery = "Insert into freigabedaten (produktname,unterprodukt,version,freigabestatus) values (@produktname,@underprodukt,@version,'4')";
```

And then declare input parameters for `MySqlCommand` inside `foreach` loop before using `ExecuteNonQuery` method:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand Command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@produktname", productInfo.Product);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unterprodukt", productInfo.Underproduct);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@version", productInfo.Version);

Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i will check u awnser in 1 houer i have a break now